# How to reduce heat on palm rest and left side of the keyboard?

Tags: laptop, maintenance

I got an Asus N43SL and it's really hot on the left hand side. I can't rest my left hand there for too long, because it's really hot.

The problem probably is its harddisk. And the air vent is there too. When I'm playing games, my hand can somehow feel the heat from the vent. It somehow heats up the upper left area of the keyboard as well. So basically the entire left area is hot (the left palm rest and the left side of the keyboard)

So, how do I reduce the heat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best suggestion is to either try to see if a BIOS/Firmware update is available If a heat issue has been detected across your model, it is possible that the fan speeds/thresholds have been increased. That being said, hard drive slots are hardly ever with a fan.

If there isn't an update available, possibly look at getting a cooling mat/stand such as this:

[image]

Comment: apparently the technical support suggest me to update my Gfx driver and BIOS.. It's not a known issue for the model, but everybody says it's normal and seems fine with the heat.